# git rebase and keep tags update

Tags: git, git-rebase

This is my git log

```
commit beba35
aaa

commit 2d34d4
bbb(tag: ATag)

commit be2f8a
cccc
```

If I use git rebase and change `be2f8a`, then I will get a new git log

```
commit as2sd2e
aaa

commit sdf2sdf
bbb

commit be2f8a
cccc
```

We know, `sdf2sdf` and `2d34d4` are same commits even if they have different commit id. But the tag will stay on `2d34d4` and will not update to `sdf2sdf`.

Is the any way to keep tag follow new commit when I use git rebase?

Comment: Note that, for the same reason it's often a bad idea to move *any* tag, it can be a bad idea to move a tag after a rebase. In particular, some other Git user may have copied the tag to their own Git, after which they may keep the "wrong" value of the tag.

Answer (score 8):

Tags are more to mark something fixed in time (a release for example). However, if you want to use tags, you can use `git tag -f tagName commitHash` manually to update it.

This being said, maybe you would want to use a branch instead of a tag. Branches are more flexible in term of being "moved around". Say you have the following:

```
commit beba35 (yourBranch)
aaa

commit 2d34d4 (yourBranchTag)
bbb

commit be2f8a
cccc

(masterBranch)
```

Instead of rebasing `yourBranch` on top of `masterBranch`, you can rebase `yourBranchTag` on top of `masterBranch` and then rebase `yourBranch` on top of `yourBranchTag`.

You end up having to maintain them in the order, but they would all stay in the same ancestors line.

Having this `yourBranchTag` branch does not mean that you will keep it or merge it, maybe it is just to keep a "bookmark" in your log. Once you are done with `yourBranch` and it's ready to be merged in `masterBranch`, you can then ditch `yourBranchTag`.

Answer (score 5):

There is no straightforward way to tell git to "move that tag along with the rebase".

You have to do it by hand :

- spot the new target commit
- (like @padawin suggested) move the tag to this commit `git tag -f ATag sdf2sdf`